# Unix parallel processing with error handling

Tags: unix, error-handling, parallel-processing

I need to run multiple scripts in parallel. The scripts needs to ensure that x scripts are always running. I trigger 6 jobs in parallel, as soon as one finishes it triggers the next one, but id something fails it should stop processing any further jobs. I was able to get hold of a script which helped me in first part, but not sure how to handle the error tracking. **I do not have GNU parallel**

```
PROCS=6
SLEEP=20
while read LINE
do
     while true
     do
         NUM=$(jobs | wc -l)
         echo NUM=$NUM
         if [ $NUM -lt $PROCS ]
         then
             stuff "$LINE" &
             break
         else
             sleep $SLEEP
         fi
    done
done < textfile
wait
```

So above ensures 6 processes are always running. I want a way to find out if one of the process is failed, then do not trigger anymore jobs.

Comment: Using a `wait` for process X and right after that calling `$?` will give you the exit code of external process which you can use as you see fit.

Comment: But if I have 6 processes running..if even one fails I should not trigger any other process. How do I track all 6 process an their exit codes? If even one process succeeds, I should trigger the next process

Comment: You can use the `waitpid` (`wait` can also do that since it has an optional argument for the PID of a process but I find it more readable this way) inside your loop which allows you to wait for a given PID (in your case you can get the PID after you execute your process in the background using `&` and then storing the result from `$!`).You can store all the PIDs in an array. In each iteration step you can run through all the stored PIDs and call `kill` to get if the process with the selected PID is running or not. If not you can get its exit code and if it's not equal to 0 just break the loop.

Comment: If you can run your own scripts you can use GNU Parallel: http://oletange.blogspot.dk/2013/04/why-not-install-gnu-parallel.html (excuse #3). If your reason for not using GNU Parallel is not covered, please elaborate why.